# statements out of while loop does not run

Tags: c

I am practicing C by following code:

```
char* streverse(char* s){
    int len=strlen(s);
    int i=0; int j=len;
    char* r;

    while(i<j){
        s[i]=s[j];
        i++; j--;
    }
    printf("\nReverse string is %s",s);
    return r;
}
```

But the printf never executes. If I remove the:

```
s[i]=s[j];
```

printf executes. This is strange because while loop ends anyway independent of above assignment. Any clues why printf doesn't execute with above assignment present?

EDIT:

By correcting the printf signature now it prints.

Comment: Undefined behaviour.

Comment: You do know that `s[strlen(s)]` is always the terminator? So guess what happens in the very first iteration of the loop...

Comment: Also, writing to `stdout` (which is what `printf` does) flushes the buffer (i.e. actually does the writing) on newline. So printing the only newline *first* in a `printf` call makes no sense.

Comment: Another also, you return `r` from the function. But nowhere do you initialize `r`.

Comment: Finally, learn how to use a *debugger*. It's an essential skill for any developer. Stepping through the code with a debugger, line by line, you would see that the algorithm you have will never work (as well as a few of the other problems you have).

Comment: Also the `streverse` doesn't reverse the whole string, it only reverses the last half and puts it in place of the first one. You should swap the characters.

Comment: @max_hassen: indeed. It will turn e.g. `"12345678"` into `"87655678"`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Almost, but not quite. It will turn `"12345678"` to `"\087655678"`.

Comment: Since we're piling on helpful advice, note that `streverse()` is a reserved name, you're not supposed to define your own functions that start with `str` since the library owns that namespace. This is a bit academic but it's good to learn good habits early. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: correct. So it appears as an empty string. But even if he'd start with `len - 1`, it would not be a reversal without proper swapping. Actually, I prefer routines that return a new string. Then you can also pass constants without the risk of an AV (or whatever it is called on a particular platform). And in that case, I prefer to fill a buffer the caller allocated.

Comment: @unwind: I thought that was a POSIX rule, not a standard rule. And there, they are reserved for future use, although I don't think anyone would name a function `streverse()`, but rather `strreverse()`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Nope, it's in the C11 draft for instance, §7.31.13: "Function names that begin with `str`, `mem`, or `wcs` and a lowercase letter may be added
to the declarations in the `<string.h>` header". I agree with the spelling issue of course but the prefix is still `str`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set `j` to `len-1` as a first change, since otherwise you're accessing `s` outside its contents. More precisely, `s[len]` is going to be a `NUL` (or character `\0`), since that's how strings are stored in C. And it is going to be swapped with the first element of the `s`, effectively making it a zero-length string / empty string.

Second, the format should just be `printf("\nReverse string is %s", s);`

Also, you should assign `r` to something before returning it (to `s` probably?), otherwise it's just going to be initialised to gibberish and cause problems down the line when you try to use it as a pointer.

Comment: _`s[len]` is going to be a `NULL`_...not really. `NULL` is not `null terminator`.

Comment: Actually, `s[len]` is not outside its *allocated* memory. The terminating `'\0'` is allocated too, but not counted by `strlen()`.

Comment: Yup, you are correct. I made the changes in the response to reflect reality

Answer (score 3):

You are passing `%s` as format specifier which expects a string argument but passing integer value `i` as the value.